# how can i create a new array containing just with member tickets

Tags: javascript

how can i create a new array containing just with member tickets

```
[ 
  { 
    "is_member_ticket":"true", 
    "is_table_ticket":"false", 
    "name":"Ticket (C)", 
    "price":"10", 
    "id":"1362926143" 
  }, 
  { 
    "is_member_ticket":"true", 
    "is_table_ticket":"false", 
    "name":"Ticket (A)", 
    "price":"25", 
    "id":"1362926141" 
  }, 
  { 
    "is_member_ticket":"true", 
    "is_table_ticket":"false", 
    "name":" Ticket (C)", 
    "price":"10", 
    "id":"1362926142" 
  }, 
  { 
    "is_member_ticket":"false", 
    "is_table_ticket":"false", 
    "name":" Ticket (C)", 
    "price":"10", 
    "id":"1362926147" 
  }, 
  { 
    "is_member_ticket":"false", 
    "is_table_ticket":"false", 
    "name":" Ticket (C)", 
    "price":"10", 
    "id":"1362926146" 
  }
]
```

Comment: need to provide a data structure of the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method of Array like that:

```js
const memberList = [{
    "is_member_ticket": "true",
    "is_table_ticket": "false",
    "name": "Ticket (C)",
    "price": "10",
    "id": "1362926143"
}, {
    "is_member_ticket": "true",
    "is_table_ticket": "false",
    "name": "Ticket (A)",
    "price": "25",
    "id": "1362926141"
}, {
    "is_member_ticket": "true",
    "is_table_ticket": "false",
    "name": " Ticket (C)",
    "price": "10",
    "id": "1362926142"
}, {
    "is_member_ticket": "false",
    "is_table_ticket": "false",
    "name": " Ticket (C)",
    "price": "10",
    "id": "1362926147"
}, {
    "is_member_ticket": "false",
    "is_table_ticket": "false",
    "name": " Ticket (C)",
    "price": "10",
    "id": "1362926146"
}];

const members = memberList.filter(elem => elem.is_member_ticket === "true");

/* without arrow function looks like */
const members2 = memberList.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.is_member_ticket === "true";
});

console.log(members);

console.log(members2);
```

`.filter()` uses a callback that must return `true` or `false` for filter the elements into your array.